# Magento -2 homepage top navigation

Tags: magento2, navigation, topmenu, home-page

I am messing with this problem for two days, i want my horizontal menu to appear on all pages except the homepage.
my homepage shows both vertical and horizontal menu, however, i just want vertical menu to appear on the home page and horizontal menu to appear on all other pages.
here is the code of

> /app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml <

```
 <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <container name="top.container" as="topContainer" label="After Page Header Top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="top-container"/>

        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="navigation.sections" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/sections.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="group_name" xsi:type="string">navigation-sections</argument>
                <argument name="group_css" xsi:type="string">nav-sections</argument>
            </arguments>

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">

                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/sidebarmenu.phtml" ttl="3600"/>
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="main_menu">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">main_menu</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
```

Can someone guide me what should I do so that the horizontal menu does not appear on the front-page but appear on all other pages?

I've asked this question two times before, and now I'm asking this for the third time.
dear seniors and experienced fellows guide me.
this is what i've tried on

> /app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/Magento_Theme/page_layout/1column.xml <

code below:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
   <referenceBlock name="main_menu" remove="true"/>
    <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="sidebar.main" after="-"/>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar-filter sidebar zoo-sidebar-main" before="main" htmlId="sidebar-without">
            <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
   </refrenceBlock> 
</layout>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @piyush now magento is giving me "Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'name': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'magento/main-menu' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z\d\-_\.]*'. Line: 2 Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'name': 'magento/main-menu' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'elementNameType'. Line: 2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to admin panel, Select **Content->Pages** from Menu and edit your homepage.

Then on edit page Under **Design** tab add below code for **Layout Update XML** input

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <referenceBlock name="name_of_your_horizontal_menu_block" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>
```

change reference  block name with your horizontal menu block name

Comment: magento is giving me the following error when i'm trying to save

Comment: Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'referenceBlock': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move ). Line: 1

Comment: nothing changed piyush. is there some other way?

Comment: this will work, you have to define proper name for both tags

Comment: <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <referenceBlock name="main_menu" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>      
i used this but still no change.

Comment: i didn't get what you mean by proper tags? refrenceContainer & refrenceBlock are the tags right! and they seem ok

Comment: I mean by name attribute of those tags.

Comment: should i replace "main_menu" which is block name , with "magento/cms/blcok/main_menu"?
i mean is that what you are trying to tell?

Comment: ,magento is giving me the following error now "Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'name': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'magento/main-menu' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z\d\-_\.]*'. Line: 2 Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'name': 'magento/main-menu' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'elementNameType'. Line: 2"

Comment: you need to add name of the block and not the block class

Comment: may I know which extension you are using to show horizontal menu?

Comment: my block name is "main_menu" 
and title is "Home 01 main menu"
and block id is "89"

Comment: extension name is cleverMegamenu